# Convolution seemingly not commutative

Tags: convolution

I think I don't quite get how convolution works.

It should be defined as:
$$
    f \star g(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(y-x)\, dx 
$$
Now, my two functions are:

```
f(x) = 1 if x in [-1, 1] else 0
g(x) = 1 - x^2 if x in [-1, 1] else 0
```

According to the slides, `f*g = g*f`, but that is inconsistent with the definition, since `g*f` wouldn't even "contain" `y` (function `f` doesn't care about its argument), while the opposite does.

It seems to me that in this case `f*g(y) = -2y^2 + 4/3`, but `g*f` wouldn't even contain `y` in its answer.

How is that?

Comment: Take into account that $f$ is not constant: it is $1$ in the interval $[-1,1]$ and $0$ otherwise. You need to consider different cases while calculating the integral.

Comment: Are you sure that $g \star f$ does not depend on $y$ ? Notice the definition of $f$: We get
$$
f(y-x) = \begin{cases}
1&, -1 \leq y -x \leq 1 \\
0&~ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that $f(x)g(y-x) = 0$ whenever $x < -1$ or $x > 1,$

\begin{align}
f \star g(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(y-x)\, dx  \\
 &= \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(y-x)\, dx  \\
 &= \int_{-1}^1 g(y-x)\, dx  \\
 &= -\int_{y+1}^{y-1} g(t)\, dt  && t = y - x \\
 &= \int_{y-1}^{y+1} g(t)\, dt.
\end{align}

But also $g(x)f(y-x) = 0$ whenever $y-x < -1$ or $y-x > 1$, that is to say,
whenever $x > y+1$ or $x < y-1,$ so

\begin{align}
g \star f(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(y-x)\, dx  \\
 &= \int_{y-1}^{y+1} g(x)f(y-x)\, dx  \\
 &= \int_{y-1}^{y+1} g(x)\, dx .
\end{align}

The final value of the integral either way is not as simple as 
$-2y^2 + \frac43.$
If $y \leq -2$ or $y \geq 2$ the integral is zero.
If $y = 0$ then

\begin{align}
g \star f(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(-x)\, dx  \\
&= \int_{-1}^{1} g(x)\, dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^{1} (1 - x^2)\, dx \\
&= 2 - \left. \frac{x^3}{3}\right\rvert_{x=-1}^{x=1} \\
&= \frac 43.
\end{align}

But if $0 < y < 2$ then $f(y - x) = 0$ whenever $x < y - 1,$
and $g(x) = 0$ whenever $x > 1,$ so

\begin{align}
g \star f(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(y-x)\, dx  \\
g \star f(y) &= \int_{y-1}^{1} g(x) \, dx \\
g \star f(y) &= \int_{y-1}^{1} (1 - x^2)\, dx \\
&= (2 - y) - \left. \frac{x^3}{3}\right\rvert_{x=y-1}^{x=1} \\
&= \frac{y^3}{3} - y^2 +  \frac 43.
\end{align}

And if $-2 < y < 0$ then $f(y - x) = 0$ whenever $x > y + 1,$
and $g(x) = 0$ whenever $x < -1,$ and the result is

\begin{align}
g \star f(y) &= -\frac{y^3}{3} - y^2 +  \frac 43.
\end{align}

So $g\star f(y)$ depends very much on $y$.

Moreover, your calculation of $f\star g(y)$ is incorrect.
You need to account for the fact that $g(x)=1 - x^2$ on all of $[y-1,y+1]$ only when $y = 0.$ For $y > 0,$ $g(x)=1 - x^2$ on $[y-1,1]$ and $g(x) = 0$ otherwise. 
Indeed, you should end up integrating the exact same integrals as for $g\star f.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\begin{align}
(f\star g)(y) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) g(y-x)~dx\\\\
(g\star f)(y) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(t) f(y-t)~dt=\\\\ &=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(y-t) g(t) ~dt
\end{align}$$

Now think about [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) to change the third integral into the first one.

Comment: Thank you, but I know the proof, but I need to see why my concrete counterexample is wrong.